# Windows Script to consolidate files

Tags: windows, powershell

I have to work with a huge number of text files. I am able to consolidate the files into one single file. But I also have the use of the file name in my work and I would like to have it before the text of the file itself in excel format, preferably the first column should contain the names of files and the columns afterwards can contain the data.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Which programmer language do you want to use?

Comment: Windows Script. I have Powershell

Comment: Post your actual script. It's a starting point for trying help you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the Powershell script. You might need to modify it a bit to look for specific file extensions as now it's only looking for PS1 files

```
[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")

$excel = new-Object -comobject Excel.Application  
$excel.visible = $false  

$workBook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
$sheet =  $workBook.Sheets.Item(1)  
$sheet.Name = "Files"
$sheet.Range("A1", "B1").Font.Bold = $true
$sheet.Range("A1","A2").ColumnWidth = 40
$sheet.Range("B1","B2").ColumnWidth = 100

$sheet.Cells.Item(1,1) = "Filename" 
$sheet.cells.Item(1,2) = "Content" 

$files = get-childitem C:\PST -recurse | where {$_.extension -eq ".ps1"}
$index = 2

foreach($file in $files)
{
    $sheet.Cells.Item($index,1) = $file.FullName
    $sheet.Cells.Item($index,2) = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($file.FullName)
    $index++
}

$workBook.SaveAs("C:\PST\1.xlsx")
$excel.Quit()
```

Note: I'm not pretending that it's perfect, you still need to polish it and refactor it, but at least it will give you direction

Comment: $workBook.SaveAs("C:\PST\1.xlsx") or $workBook.SaveAs("C:\PST\1.xls"), based on office version installated!